# Same results within Django template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

There's a registration button that creates an Attendee for that specific event.(that works). However, upon clicking 'Register', the template recognizes `'is_attending'= True`(Registered!) for every Event in `upcoming`.

View:

```
def index(request):
    upcoming = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.now())
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    is_attending = False
    for event in upcoming:
        attendees = [a.profile for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]
        if profile in attendees:
            is_attending = True
```

template

```
{% if is_attending %}
     <a><Registered!</a>
{% else %}
     <form>... registration form ... Register Now...
```

I guess what's happening is:

```
event 1  : Registered!
event 2  : Registered!
event 3  : Registered!
```

When what I need is :

```
event 1  : Registered!
event 2  : Register Now
event 3  : Register Now
```

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working for me? How do I loop through to return `is_attending` for only those who have registered within `upcoming` events?

Models:

```
class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profile = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-writing the value of  `is_attending` every time you go through the for loop; your template sees the (single) value of `is_attending` as set by whether the last event in `upcoming` is being attended by `request.user`.

To get the desired behaviour, one piece of `is_attending` info for *each* `Event`. I think the easiest way to do this is [with a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_is_attending(context, event):
    if type(event) != Event:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Must provide event")
    request = context['request']
    if event.attendee_set.filter(profile__user=request.user).exists():
        return 'attending'
    else:
        return 'not attending'
```

Then, while you're looping over your events in the template:

```
{% user_is_attending event %}
```

You could also consider using an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) or an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) depending on your needs.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think that's a fair criticism; you could use `annotate`, but OP is obviously relatively new to Django. Simplicity of concepts is up there with efficiency of execution, surely?

Comment: New I am indeed. I'm looking into assignment tags. I absolutely appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Daniel I have, however, rewritten it down to 1 query per `Event` in the hope that you no longer think it unacceptable.